# insert skips last record in recordset

Tags: java, jdbc

I am writing a program that pulls data out of one schema, restructures the data to fit a new schema, and then inserts the data into a new database with the new schema.  The problem is that, in my test code, the last record is not being inserted into the new database.

I am enclosing a greatly simplified version of the code below, which nonetheless recreates the problem.  Can anyone show me how to fix the below so that all records in the recordset are inserted into the destination database?  Currently, the below does correctly print out the last record in system.out.println, but yet that last record is not present in the destination table afterwards:

```
static void migrateDataTest(){
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection sourceConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:source_data_test");
        Statement st = sourceConn.createStatement();
        Connection destinationConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:receive_data_test");
        int ClientNumber; String ClientsLastName; String ClientsFirstName;
        ResultSet rest = st.executeQuery("SELECT ClientNumber, ClientsLastName, ClientsFirstName FROM sourceTable");
        PreparedStatement ps5 = null;
        while(rest.next()){
            ClientNumber = rest.getInt(1);
            ClientsLastName = rest.getString(2);
            ClientsFirstName = rest.getString(3);
            System.out.println(ClientNumber+", "+ClientsLastName+", "+ClientsFirstName);
            ps5 = destinationConn.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO destinationTable ("
                + "ClientNumber, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
            );
            ps5.setInt(1, ClientNumber);
            ps5.setString(2, ClientsFirstName);
            ps5.setString(3, ClientsLastName);
            ps5.executeUpdate();
            destinationConn.commit();
        }
        ps5.close();
    }
catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe){cnfe.printStackTrace();}
catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

EDIT:

As per Lokesh's request, I am putting the entire code block which creates this error below.  I just ran it again to confirm that it is printing record 30 in system.out.println, but that the destination table does not contain record number 30.  The fact that the skipped record is printing out with system.out.println causes me to believe that the code below contains the error:

```
static void migrateDataTest(){
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection sourceConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:source_test");
        Statement st = sourceConn.createStatement();
        Connection destinationConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:receive_data_test");
        int ClientNumber;
        String ClientsLastName;
        String ClientsFirstName;
        String ClientsMiddleInitial;
        Date DOB;
        int GenderNumber;
        int RaceNumber;
        ResultSet rest = st.executeQuery("SELECT ClientNumber, ClientsLastName, ClientsFirstName, ClientsMiddleInitial, DOB, GenderNumber, RaceNumber FROM sourceTable");
        PreparedStatement ps5 = null;
        while(rest.next()){
            ClientNumber = rest.getInt(1);
            ClientsLastName = rest.getString(2);
            ClientsFirstName = rest.getString(3);
            ClientsMiddleInitial = rest.getString(4);
            DOB = rest.getDate(5);
            GenderNumber = rest.getInt(6);
            RaceNumber = rest.getInt(7);
            System.out.println(ClientNumber+", "+ClientsLastName+", "+ClientsFirstName+", "+ClientsMiddleInitial+", "+DOB+", "+GenderNumber+", "+RaceNumber);  
            ps5 = destinationConn.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO destinationTable ("
                + "ClientNumber, FirstName, MiddleInitial, LastName, DOB, GenderNumber, RaceNumber) "
                +"VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            );
            ps5.setInt(1, ClientNumber);
            ps5.setString(2, ClientsFirstName);
            ps5.setString(3, ClientsMiddleInitial);
            ps5.setString(4, ClientsLastName);
            ps5.setDate(5, DOB);
            ps5.setInt(6, GenderNumber);
            ps5.setInt(7, RaceNumber);
            ps5.executeUpdate();
            destinationConn.commit();
        }
        ps5.close();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe){cnfe.printStackTrace();}
    catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: the code is OK I think, is the System.out.println printing anything?  Any exceptiosn?

Comment: @user2310289 System.out.println prints every record, including the last record, which never seems to end up in the destination table.

Comment: 1,2,4 is ok? you are inserting 3 things only.. `ps5.setString(4,..)`

Comment: How are you verifying that you're missing a record?  Are you running a `COUNT(*)` on the target table?

Comment: @nachokk Good catch.  I just changed it to 1,2,3.  The actual code inserts lots of other variables in multiple tables.  But the code above does recreate the problem without distracting everyone on this site with a bunch of irrelevant code.

Comment: @bstempi There are only 30 test records in this table, and they all have ordered keys.  Record number 30 is not inserting in the destination database, even though its name, number, and id are printed by system.out.println. The data is created using a program that I wrote myself to fill the source database with 30 test accounts. I validate the inputs and outputs at every step of my code.

Comment: @CodeMed: you need to share actual code, this code has no issues.

Comment: @Lokesh I just posted all the code required to recreate the error.  I just re-ran the code, and confirmed that it prints out the last record in the console but does not insert it in the destination table.  Does the extra code above help?

Comment: either you are throwing an exception, or you are not querying the destination correctly to see if the data is there.

Comment: @user2310289 Thank you.  If there is an exception, then why is the printStackTrace not printing anything out in the console? Also, I am opening up the tables in the MS Access user interface, which should be more reliable than any query.  I delete all records in the table, confirm the table is empty, then run the code, close and reopen the table in MS Access to see the newly inserted records, and I check each primary key and first and last name to confirm that the last item is missing by number and name, even though it prints in system.out.println. What else can I try?

Comment: @user2310289 Can I somehow print the value of ps5 to see if it is populating each time?

Comment: Is it the last values that it missing?  What is the last thing that is printed?  Try catching all Exceptions

Comment: @user2310289 Yes, the last value is missing.  I just changed SQLException e to Exception e to catch all exceptions and ran it again.  No exceptions were thrown, but only 29 records were entered.  Do you have any other ideas to try?  The last thing printed in the console is the final (30th) record: 30, Cassidy, Butch, J, 1926-05-09, 2, 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, oddly enough, was to create and execute an additional prepared statement after the one that was failing to insert the final value in its recordset.  Once I added an additional prepared statement afterwards, the first one began to consistently insert all of its values.

Seems like some nuance in java code that perhaps is missing in the code samples that I posted in my original posting above.